# Unloading icons and photos in Magento2.2.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.3

Unloading icons and photos in Magento
In general, it can be said that the admin panel does not work
[image]

Comment: Try doing php bin/magento s:s:d and then php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade setup, you need to deploy static content

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

If you got error command not working then used below

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Can you explain more please؟